# Who Stol' the 'Lac?

Tags: music-video

Back in high school I was a huge fan of Dirty and their music video Hit Da Floe, which contained a skit titled "Who Stol' the 'Lac?".

The music video explored 4 suspects in the theft of Big Pimp and Mr. G-Stacka's Cadillac.

[image: who stol it]

At the end of the music video the pimp and the G enter a residence which seems to reveal the answer, but we are not shown whatever is being revealed and instead are shown a message saying "To Be Continued...".

I've been anxiously awaiting the answer for 16 years. So -- who stol' the 'lac??